# How does the lambda syntax of ASP.NET configurations work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For example, in configuring the app, you commonly get

```
app.AddConfiguration(options => 
{
    options.DoThing();
    options.ReadParameters(parameters);
    options.UseOtherConfig(config =>
    {
        config.DoConfigThing(options.SomeValue);
    }
}
```

How do I mentally parse what's going on here?

Where do `options` and `config` objects come from? Are they created on the fly from the interfaces specified (e.g. if it had the signature `app.AddConfiguration(IOptions options)`? How does the second nesting retrieve a value if nothing is set? Should I assume this is set by ASP.NET at runtime somewhere, and I'm not supposed to "care"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will pass a function to `AddConfiguration` that looks like this:

```
public void HandleAddConfiguration(IConfiguration options) {
  options.DoThing();
  options.ReadParameters(parameters);
  options.UseOtherConfig(config =>
  {
     config.DoConfigThing(options.SomeValue);
  }
}
```

and then call it like

```
app.AddConfiguration(HandleAddConfiguration);
```

This syntax might make things a little more clear. The syntax you are using is called [lambda-expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).

This lambda function will be called by `AddConfiguration` function like this (simplified example):

```
public void AddConfiguration(Action<IConfiguration> configAction) {
 IConfiguration config = new Configuration();
 configAction(config);
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense.